# How to allow users with a link to view documents

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I own a Google account, and use Docs (spreadsheet in Drive) to make a document to be shared with anyone having the link.

However the only options available (in Sharing) are

- share with people of the organization
- share with people of the organization mentioned below
- share only with people mentioned below

There is no Share with "Anyone with the link". I tried to change the settings but that doesn't seem to be possible.

**From a Google account, how to I make a Google doc (spreadsheet/Drive) visible to anyone having the link?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Admin Console, click on the Google Apps logo:
[image]
and select Google Drive:
[image]
In de Google Drive area, select "Sharing Settings":
[image]
and select this option:
[image]

Start URL's:

- https://admin.google.com/url/AdminHome#Home
- https://admin.google.com/url/AdminHome#AppDetails:service=Drive+and+Docs&flyout=sharing

Answer (score -1):

try this, if you are not already trying.

open the document, click on share document, there you will see the link on the top, Click "Change" under "who has access". you will what to do further,

Also use the new version of gmail and do check your permissions for the document. Check if you are the owner of the document or not!

Comment: I have checked it just now. and its working fine for me !

Comment: I use a Google Account (not a simple Gmail). And unfortunately that option is not present. It requires probably a setup somewhere.